# UICollectionView scroll to item at Index

Tags: xcode, swift, uicollectionview

I've succeeded to scroll item at index e.g. if the user taps a button it's goes to the last item

Here is the code that i've used

```
 self.collection.scrollToItemAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forItem: self.array.count - 1, inSection: 0), atScrollPosition: UICollectionViewScrollPosition.Top, animated: true)
```

But my issue **is how to know if a user is at the bottom or at the top of the `UICollectionView`?**

I can do this by creating 2 functions and if a user taps on the TOP `UIButton` it goes up and vice versa...

But I only want to do this with a single `UIButton`. so that if the user presses on the button the code should know if a user is at the bottom and goes up and vice versa.
I looked at each function at `UICollectionView` but doesn't seem to `return` at which item the user at.

I thought of something which logically might be correct as this one

```
var someBool: Bool!

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
 let tempIndex: Int = self.array.count / 2 

 if indexPath.row > tempIndex{
   someBool = true // UP
 } else {
  someBool = false // Down
 }
 ...
}

@IBAction func buttonPressed{
   if someBool{
     self.collection.scrollToItemAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forItem: 0, inSection: 0), atScrollPosition: UICollectionViewScrollPosition.Top, animated: true) 
   } else {
     self.collection.scrollToItemAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forItem: self.array.count - 1, inSection: 0), atScrollPosition: UICollectionViewScrollPosition.Top, animated: true) 
   }
}
```

This Mean let's assume an array has 9 elements / 2 = 4 (INT) so if the user selects item 9, 9 > 4 true go up else down.

I believe this code works well only if the user selects an item, but I need an alternative way without using the `indexPath.row` because, let's assume the user didn't select any item... so this code won't work....

Comment: Can you use the collection view's `contentOffset` property? (If not, can you explain why that won't work for you?)

Comment: uhmm, `contentOffset` ? what this property do ? could you show me a code sample?

Comment: See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScrollView/contentOffset and http://www.objc.io/issues/3-views/scroll-view/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if you are supporting from **iOS 8.0**

```
optional func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
             willDisplayCell cell: UICollectionViewCell,
          forItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
```

This new API is use full so your code will be perfectly worked just move your code  from `didSelectItemAtIndexPath`  to this method because it calls every time and check your `indexpath.row` here. let me know if it helps.